# Web scraping with rvest, values come out as "0"

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am digging deeper into R with a private Covid-Project:
http://members.chello.at/charmingquark/Covid19_Report_v2.1.html

Now I tried to extend the gathered info with some numbers scraped with `rvest` from this website:
https://info.gesundheitsministerium.gv.at/

In a first step I would like to get the numbers shown as text and later on the numbers from the map:
[numbers - info.gesundheitsministerium.gv.at/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYxke.jpg)

I went through some tutorials and tested a view things which all worked out but in this case I am just getting back zeros...

```
cov_impf_db_url <- read_html("https://info.gesundheitsministerium.gv.at/")

cov_impf_db_url %>% 
  html_nodes(".text-5xl.tabular-nums") %>% 
  html_text()
```

which results in

```
[1] "0" "0" "0"
```

if I just use

```
cov_impf_db_url %>% 
  html_nodes(".text-5xl.tabular-nums")
```

I get

```
{xml_nodeset (3)}
[1] <p class="text-5xl tabular-nums" id="Vaccinations">0</p>
[2] <p class="text-5xl tabular-nums" id="estimatedVaccinations">0</p>
[3] <p class="text-5xl tabular-nums" id="deliveredVaccinations">0</p>
```

fitting the former output but when I look at the website there are a values other than "0", for example:

```
<p class="text-5xl tabular-nums" id="Vaccinations">63.280</p>
```

I just started with rvest and never worked with html so I am a bit lost and grateful for any tips.
thanks,
c|q

---

Just found an alternative via this post:
[rvest web scraping with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50381758/rvest-web-scraping-with-javascript)

There are 2 csv-files in the background:
https://info.gesundheitsministerium.gv.at/data/laender.csv
https://info.gesundheitsministerium.gv.at/data/national.csv

I am going to work with these but would still be interested in the solution to the original problem...
thx

Comment: Those numbers are inserted into the page dynamically using javascript, so `rvest` will not work here. The solution which you have found is good way. You could add it as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers load dynamically; thus, instead of `rvest`, one could use `RSelenium` to fetch the data.

It works for me with this code:

```
cov_impf_db_url <- "https://info.gesundheitsministerium.gv.at/"

rD <- RSelenium::rsDriver(browser="firefox")
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate(cov_impf_db_url)

# scroll down a bit and wait some seconds
remDr$executeScript(paste("scroll(0,",i*10000,");")) 
Sys.sleep(5)

# fetch the html code
cov_impf_db <- remDr$getPageSource()
cov_impf_db <- xml2::read_html(cov_impf_db[[1]])

# read the numbers
cov_data <- rvest::html_nodes(cov_impf_db, ".text-5xl.tabular-nums")
cov_data <- rvest::html_text(cov_data)

# end the session
remDr$close()
gc()
rD$server$stop()
system("taskkill /im java.exe /f", intern=FALSE, ignore.stdout=FALSE)
```